# C# Calculator with memory buttons

Tags: c#, memory, calculator

I am having some difficulties making my calculator have the ability to store values. The calculator works for everything except this and I am quite stuck. I think I might have to declare some constants or something that I am missing right now. I am super new at this and appreciate the help. Here is my code. Thanks for any help guys. Right now I am getting no errors but nothing works either! I am also supposed to make it so a "M" appears in a textbox when there is a value stored in memory but I figured it was easier to start with this part.

```
private void digitCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Button ButtonThatWasPushed = (Button)sender;
        string ButtonText = ButtonThatWasPushed.Text;
        decimal EndResult = 0;
        decimal MemoryStore = 0;

        if (ButtonText == "MC")
        {
            //Memory Clear
            MemoryStore = 0;
            return;
        }

        if (ButtonText == "MR")
        {
            //Memory Recall
            txtDisplay.Text = MemoryStore.ToString();
            return;
        }

        if (ButtonText == "MS")
        {
            // Memory subtract
            MemoryStore -= EndResult;
            return;
        }

        if (ButtonText == "M+")
        {
            // Memory add 

            MemoryStore += EndResult;
            return;

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the variable MemoryStore to a global variable. At the moment, it is being re-declared each time a button is pushed, meaning that the data is lost between button presses. Move it outside of the function, and it should work fine.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have Form level variable for `decimal MemoryStore = 0;` , since you have function level variable it will initialized to `0` when you click on `digitCalculate` button

```
    decimal MemoryStore = 0;
    decimal EndResult = 0;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void digitCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Button ButtonThatWasPushed = (Button)sender;
        string ButtonText = ButtonThatWasPushed.Text;
        //decimal EndResult = 0;
        //decimal MemoryStore = 0;
```

And also note that

- **MC** = Memory Clear sets the memory to 0
- **MR** = Memory Recall uses the
  number in memory
- **MS** = Memory Store puts the number on the display into the memory

You nee to change `"MS"` logic and add `"M-"`

```
    if (ButtonText == "MS")
    {
        MemoryStore = Decimal.Parse(txtDisplay.Text);
        return;
    }

    if (ButtonText == "M-")
    {
        // Memory subtract
        MemoryStore -= EndResult;
        txtDisplay.Text = MemoryStore.ToString();
        return;
    }

    if (ButtonText == "M+")
    {
        // Memory add 

        MemoryStore += EndResult;
        txtDisplay.Text = MemoryStore.ToString();
        return;

    }
```

Comment: So when I add that line I get MemoryStore is assigned but its value is never used.

Comment: also should I move decimal EndResult = 0; outside as well? I tried it and it didn't help

Comment: I tried it and played some more. It looks like it should be working but it just isn't.... :( I don't even know where the prob could be. Thanks for the help though!